# jQuery datatable shows only one row but JSON includes all records

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, datatables

I've created JSON that is valid and includes all records from a database. I checked it and verified it online. But the problem is that when I bind this with jQuery DataTables, it only shows the first row in table.

**JavaScript**

```
$('#datatable').DataTable({
    "aLengthMenu": [
       [25, 50, 75, -1],
       [25, 50, 75, "All"]
    ],
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    columns: [
       { 'data': 'Training/Program Code'}, 
       { 'data': 'Training Date And Duration Year'}, 
       { 'data': 'Training/Program Name' }, 
       { 'data': 'RADP-N Partner Name' }, 
       { 'data': 'Reporting Month ' }, 
       { 'data': 'Training/Program Location' }, 
       { 'data': 'Is this training related to nutrition'}
    ]
 });
```

**HTML**

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <td>Training/Program Code</td>
    <td>Training/Program Code</td>
    <td>Training Date And Duration Year</td>
    <td>RADP-N Partner Name</td>
    <td>Reporting Month </td>
    <td>Training/Program Location</td>
</tr>
</thead>
```

Why does it only display one row? I checked my JSON, and it displays all records.

Comment: Please show content of your JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

Your columns are your table headers (thus the nesting within thead > tr)

The data is defined by the data attribute in your **DataTable** declaration-

```
$('#datatable').DataTable( {
    data: data
} );
```